# Creating a list of composite names separated by underscore given a data frame

Tags: python, pandas

We are given a data frame that may look like this (I am sorry I wasn't able to show the data frame given the code below):

```
    import pandas as pd   
    data = {'ID':['HA12','HA12','HA12','HA20', 'HA20' ], 'Age': [20, 20, 20, 25, 25], 'Gender': ['M','M','M','F','F'], 'Classes':['Maths', 'Biology', 'Chemistry', 'Maths', 'English' ]}   
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)   
    print(df)
```

I want to create a list out of the data frame that I will use to name the columns of another data frame. Each element of the list should be composed of names that I want to select and separated by an underscore. You may observe that entries in many columns of the above data frame are the same. Moreover, the age was not included in any of the composite names. More precisely, the list should look like this:

```
List = ['HA12_M_Maths','HA12_M_Biology','HA12_M_Chemistry','HA20_F_Maths','HA20_F_English']
```

I tried something but was unsuccessful in creating the list that I need.

I will appreciate any suggestion or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
out=(df['ID']+'_'+df['Gender']+'_'+df['Classes']).tolist()
```

**OR**

```
out=df[['ID','Gender','Classes']].agg('_'.join,1).tolist()
```

output of `out`:

```
['HA12_M_Maths', 'HA12_M_Biology', 'HA12_M_Chemistry', 'HA20_F_Maths', 'HA20_F_English']
```

**Note:** If needed a list of unique elements then just chain `.unique()` to any of these method....For example:

```
out=(df['ID']+'_'+df['Gender']+'_'+df['Classes']).unique().tolist()
#OR
out=df[['ID','Gender','Classes']].agg('_'.join,1).unique().tolist()
```

Comment: Great. Both possibilities worked fine. Many thanks.

Comment: @user249018 updated answer added a note......kindly have a look **:)**

Comment: unique in the sense let's say this code `df[['ID','Gender','Classes']].agg('_'.join,1)` gives a series of value so lets say if this series contains duplicated entries for example `'HA12_M_Maths'` exists 2 times in the series and when you use `tolist()` method on it then the list you get contains 2 entries of `'HA12_M_Maths'` i.e `['HA12_M_Maths','HA12_M_Maths',.....]` so if you chain `unique()` method and then `tolist()` method then you will get unique entries i.e `'HA12_M_Maths'` conatins only a single entry in your list so you will get `['HA12_M_Maths',.....]`

Comment: @ Anurag Dabas I have an additional issue. I case there is a number in a name and a blank space to the name it belongs to, I would like to delete the blank space. So, instead of `HA12_8 M_Maths` I want to have `HA12_8M_Maths`. Is this doable ?

Comment: @user249018 yes...just do `df['ID']=df['ID'].str.strip()` and  `df['Gender']=df['Gender'].str.strip()`   then follow along with answer :)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately is not working. I first got an error message, saying 'can only use .str accessor with string values'. But somehow I fixed it. I nevertheless do not get rid of the blank space. `dfb['id']=dfb['id'].astype(str).str.strip()
dfb['age']=dfb['age'].astype(str).str.strip()
 columns=(dfb['id'].apply(str)+'_'+dfb['age']+'_'+dfb['structure_acronym']+'_'+dfb['gender']).tolist()`. What I get as output is: ['12304_40 yrs_M1C_F',
 '12304_40 yrs_HIP_F'], instaed of ['12304_40yrs_M1C_F',
 '12304_40yrs_HIP_F']

Comment: `strip()` only remove the `' '` on left side and right side on the string so if you want to remove `' '` in anywhere then use `replace()` instead.....i.e `dfb['id'].astype(str).str.replace(' ','')`1